# Using a Hibernate filter with Spring Boot JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have found the need to limit the size of a child collection by a property in the child class.

I have the following after following [this guide](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-data-filter-example-xml-and-annotation/):

```
@FilterDef(name="dateFilter", parameters=@ParamDef( name="fromDate", type="date" ) )
public class SystemNode implements Serializable {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Builder.Default
    // "startTime" is a property in HealthHistory
    @Filter(name = "dateFilter", condition = "startTime >= :fromDate")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "system", targetEntity = HealthHistory.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<HealthHistory> healthHistory = new HashSet<HealthHistory>();

    public void addHealthHistory(HealthHistory health) {
        this.healthHistory.add(health);
        health.setSystem(this);
    }
}
```

However, I don't really understand how to toggle this filter when using Spring Data JPA. I am fetching my parent entity like this:

```
public SystemNode getSystem(UUID uuid) {
    return systemRepository.findByUuid(uuid)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Could not find system with id " + uuid));
}
```

And this method in turn calls the Spring supported repository interface:

```
public interface SystemRepository extends CrudRepository<SystemNode, UUID> {

    Optional<SystemNode> findByUuid(UUID uuid);

}
```

How can I make this filter play nicely together with Spring? I would like to activate it programatically *when I need it*, not globally. There are scenarios where it would be viable to disregard the filter.

I am using Spring Boot `1.3.5.RELEASE`, I cannot update this at the moment.

Comment: I think you could enable it for 1 call and immediatly disable it again. An example can be found [here](https://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/hibernate-filter-and-filterjointable-annotation-example)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I have found that source, but that forces me to circumvent the Spring repository entirely and use HQL to define my own query. I want to avoid that if possible, but I don't know if it is.

Comment: No it doesn't. Before calling the repository method get hold of the `EntityManager`. Use `EntityManager.unwrap(Session.class)` to get the underlying Hibernate Session. Call `enableFilter`, call the repository method, call `disableFilter`.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks, I will give it a try!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update and solution**

I tried the following as suggested to me in the comments above.

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;

public SystemNode getSystemWithHistoryFrom(UUID uuid) {
    Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

    Filter filter = session.enableFilter("dateFilter");
    filter.setParameter("fromDate", new DateTime().minusHours(4).toDate());

    SystemNode systemNode = systemRepository.findByUuid(uuid)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Could not find system with id " + uuid));

    session.disableFilter("dateFilter");

    return systemNode;
}
```

I also had the wrong type in the `FilterDef` annotation:

```
@FilterDef(name="dateFilter", parameters=@ParamDef( name="fromDate", type="timestamp" ) )
```

I changed from `date` to `timestamp`.

This returns the correct number of objects, verified against the database.

Thank you!

Comment: And what when in parent entity I have OneToMany and then I'd like to add condition on third nested entity like A.fieldB.fieldC.fieldD.id = x... How to achieve this with Filter in this case?

Comment: I don't understand why you need a hibernate filter here. You could use any filtering method you want here. The only way a hibernate filter could be useful is if you can enable it from several endpoints at once (using an aspect, for example ?).

Comment: @AdrienH this answer is over four years old, a lot has probably happened since then.